# Второй миллионер на стеке! Поздравляем!

Tags: обсуждение

На днях Gordon Linoff взял отметку в миллион очков репутации. Он стал вторым миллионером, наряду с Jon Skeet.

[Congratulations for reaching a million, Gordon Linoff!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400506/5045688). Поздравляем!

---

Ребята, мы отстаём, надо поднажать! Предлагаю заплюсовать нашего официального бота (вы понимаете о ком я).

P.S. На его месте должен был быть я...

Comment: _На его месте должен был быть я_ - на месте  официального бота или Гордона?

Comment: _(вы понимаете о ком я)_ - я не понимаю:(

Comment: Наглость, я ждал когда у него будет 1М, чтобы сделать _translation_ оффвопроса, даже вот квери имеется: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1273627/who-is-next-jon-skeet

Comment: @EOF дух наверно ...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Вряд ли. Как Духа заплюсовать? У него нет сообщений.

Comment: @EOF Ну, других о16ициальных  ботов нет ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica зато, в последнее время, неофициальных ботов полно:)

Comment: @EOF Их плюсовать не будем... ;)

Comment: Надо просто или набрать нам раз в 10 больше народу, или в 10 раз чаще ставить плюсики :)

Comment: @Harry, или одно из двух :-D

Comment: Наконец-то! Отметился тот, о ком речь. Все знают, что Грунди - бот. :)

Comment: @Grundy -- bot?!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Grundy -- bot?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor - шутка это такая. Из чата.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov линк покажешь?